# Отображение 'left-pointing angle bracket' в браузере

Tags: css, html5, google-chrome

Отображение таких-вот *скобочек* стало занимать в браузере Chrome по высоте много места. Раньше такой проблемы не было. Где *накосячил* не пойму.

```
<select style="border:0; width:70px; height:26px; font-size:12px;">
       <option value="n_1" selected="selected">&#9001;All&#9002;</option>
       <option value="n_2">X</option>
       <option value="n_3">Y</option>
</select>
```

или так :

```
    <select style="border:0; width:70px; height:26px; font-size:12px;">
       <option value="n_1" selected="selected">&lang;All&rang;</option>
       <option value="n_2">X</option>
       <option value="n_3">Y</option>
    </select>
```

Начал искать по теме, например, [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139696/why-html-entity-doesnt-work-on-win-chrome), но так и не разобрался...
Ячейку таблицы растягивает по высоте с такими символами :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<table border="1"><tr><td>
<select style="border:0; width:270px; height:26px; font-size:12px;">
       <option value="n_1" selected="selected">&#9001;All&#9002;</option>
       <option value="n_2">X</option>
       <option value="n_3">Y</option>
</select>
</td></tr></table>
```

Спасибо.